# What do i do to make alert dialog pop up when the app opens?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;


  @override
  void initState()  {
    super.initState();

    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        testAlert(context);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    subscription.cancel();
  }
```

Even with no internet the alert box does'nt trigger
Do i need a builder for this to work?

Full Code
https://github.com/swojas/plasma-donation

Answer (score 0):

It might be too early to have the context, maybe better do sth like this in the build method

```
If (subscription == null) subscription = ...
```

Another reason this could happen is if this widget is disposed by the time the stream has a value.. in this case move it to your home page since it will never be closed

Comment: can you check my source code https://github.com/swojas/plasma-donation

Answer (score 0):

I think that your alert is not triggering because you are subscribing to network changes. And within the milliseconds of staring the application, nothing changes.

Could you try this and let me know if it works?

```
result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
```

Comment: you can check my source code if you want https://github.com/swojas/plasma-donation

Comment: Please check whether the above method works :)